# PolarPlot with InterpolatingFunction not working?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

So I have solved a PDE with `NDSolve` which returns `h -> InterpolatingFunction`. I can happily plot the results with

```
Plot[h[θ, 0] /. sol, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

which returns the correct initial condition. In this case let's say the initial condition was $h(\theta, 0) = 3/2$.

`Plot` returns

[image]

as expected.

However,

```
PolarPlot[h[θ, 0] /. sol, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

returns nothing.

I can hack around it, by discretising and using `ListPolarPlot` as follows:

```
pt = Table[{θ, Part[h[θ, 0] /. sol, 1]}, {θ, 0, 2π, 0.001}]
ListPolarPlot[pt, Joined -> True]
```

which gives the required result

[image]

So my question is why does `PolarPlot` not like `InterpolatingFunction` ?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `Evaluate[]` to your `PolarPlot[]`?

Comment: Please post your `NDSolve`, so that others can run your code.

Comment: @J.M. `Evaluate` did the trick! Any reason why `PolarPlot` requires `Evaluate` but `Plot` doesn't?

Comment: Note that `PolarPlot[]` is only a convenient wrapper to `ParametricPlot[]`, using the usual conversion formulae. I suspect that without the `Evaluate[]`, the required parametric equations cannot be formed, and the result is what you observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/posting-answers-in-comments), I will expand on @J.M.'s comment to provide this question with an answer.

Since I dont have the code for your `NDSolve` I came up with (based on *Mathematica* documentation):

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[h[t, x], t] == D[h[t, x], x, x], h[0, x] == 3/2, 
h[t, 0] == 3/2, h[t, 5] == 3/2}, h, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}];
```

This done, you should obtain the plot you wanted from the command:

```
PolarPlot[Evaluate[h[t, 0] /. sol], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

Note: In my computer the command `Evaluate` was not necessary (Windows 8, *Mathematica* 10).

As a curiosity, be aware that the following command does ***NOT*** work:

```
PolarPlot[h[t, 0] /. sol, {t, 0, 2 π}, Evaluated->True]
```

For some reason `Evaluated` is not defined for `PolarPlot`. This is a sometimes simpler way to evaluate your functions within `Plot`.

Comment: @J.M. Did my `@JM` at the beginning of the answer alert you to this answer? Wasn't expecting such fast edit... :P

Comment: No, but I do monitor new answers, as part of my janitorial responsibilities. ;)